# CPT as Product in WooCommerce

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a Custom Post Type called **Master** and I want it to populate also the WooCommerce **Product** CPT without adding *New Product* on the WC Menu.

In summary, when you add a *New Master* it creates a new post type and a *New Product* in WC Products menu.

I read that a good way to do this is setting **Product** as child of **Master**, is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a cpt for this, you can create a new product type with the wc api. You will have your new product type in the same product-edit admin page.

Comment: I tried that option and works well, BTW I have a the **Master** CPT populated with information, and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: Is there a way to connect the CPT with the WC Product Type?

Comment: Yes if you populate one field connected to your cpt id from your product or the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

I investigate this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cpt-woo-integration/

Custom Post Type Woocommerce Integration Process Summery look like below code :

Step 1:

```
<?php


class CPTProductDataStore extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT {
    

    /**
     * Method to read a product from the database.
     *
     * @param WC_Product
     */
    public function read( &$product ) {
        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( ( ! $product->get_id() || ! ( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || 'product' !== $post_object->post_type ) ) {
            // throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $id = $product->get_id();

        $product->set_props(
            [
                'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
                'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
                'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
                'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
                'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
                'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
                'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
                'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
                'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
                'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
            ]
        );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_read', $id );
    }

}
```

Step 2:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'woocommerce_data_stores' );

function woocommerce_data_stores ( $stores ) {      
    $stores['product'] = 'CPTProductDataStore';
    return $stores;
}
```

Step 3:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {
 
        $price = 100; // Calculate your Price here.        
    
    return $price;
}
```